# Identify Barcode and Date with PDFBox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am reading all fields from a PDF using PDFBox in Java. I am able to identify all types of fields listed in my form (textfields, checkboxes, etc) but have a problem with the Barcode or textfields that contain a date.

In detail, i have a field as seen in the image below, which containts a date:
[image]

This field is identified by PDFBox as **PDTextField** . Is there a way to retrieve also the type of content this textfield may have ? In this case "date" .

The face the same issue with Barcodes. PDFBox identifies those fields as Textfields but i cannot identify if that textfield contains a barcode.

Is there a way to retrieve that information with PDFBox ? Please note, i am not interested in the value, i am interested in identifying the type of component used inside a textfield.

Comment: PDF out of the box does not know date fields or barcode fields. But PDF fields can be customized using Javascript. To identify customized field behavior, therefore, you have to analyze the JavaScript code associated with the events of the fields in question. As long as all your PDF custom form fields are created by the same software product, simple string comparisons might do. A generic solution, though, would be somewhere between very difficult and impossible. (Actually some text field types can be recognized by field flags: password, fileselect, comb; but not the ones you named.)

Comment: That is very helpful . Thank you.